# Table using divs - no y overflow for row

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-6

I am trying to create a table using divs. (I can't use table, tr & td tags)

The problem is:

- my cells must be next to each other (I use `float:left`)
- My row should never expand vertically, but can grow on the x-axis.

So here is my HTML :

```
<div id="table">
  <div class="rowHeader">

  </div>
  <div class="row">
      <div class="cell">bla</div>
      <div class="cell">bla</div>
      <div class="cell">bla</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
      <div class="cell">bla2</div>
      <div class="cell">bla2</div>
      <div class="cell">bla2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and CSS :

```
#table {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

.row {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: table-row;
}

.cell {
  float: left;
  display: table-cell;
  margin: 1px;
  padding: 2px;
  width: 35%;
  background: #ff3434;
```

}

Any suggestions ?

**WARNING** : My website should be working on IE6 (please avoid CSS3 / or provide an alternative way) ... FML =)

DEMO : [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kLetE/2/)

---

**EDIT**

Same problem using `display:block/inline-block`

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kLetE/3/)

Comment: `display:table-cell` is not supported by IE below IE8: http://caniuse.com/css-table

Comment: edited to show the same problem with different display properties

Comment: Why not use a table - when it is data you should. (semantics).

Comment: @JohanVdR I will not contains only data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're using `width: 100%` you're forcing the div table to be that width. Use `min-width: 100%` for the table instead and remove the `float: left` of the cell div's and the width of the row.
See it here: http://jsfiddle.net/C6UgT/1/

**EDIT:**

If you want to keep the width of the cells and get a horizontal scrollbar in the table only when the width of this is wider than the body, you must add the property `overflow-x: auto;` and `white-space: nowrap;` to the parent element (table):

```
#table {
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 100%;
    overflow-x: auto;

}
```

And use the proprety `display: inline-block;` for the child elements (cells):

```
.cell {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 1px;
    padding: 2px;
    min-width: 35%;
    background: #ff3434;
}
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/C6UgT/5/

Comment: I want to same result but with a X-scroll bar on the table if the content of a row exceed the width of the body. Here some cells are smaller than they should.

Comment: That's perfect ! Edit you answer and I'll accept it =)

Comment: I was missing the `white-space: nowrap;` thing

Comment: Any idea about why my cells looks like they have a 5px margin ? (that's the reason why i used to set `float:left`...)

Comment: Yes, it's just the white space between divs. When they're in a new line this white space is rendered. Put all the div tags in a row and it will be fine: http://jsfiddle.net/C6UgT/6/

Answer (score 0):

Try to re-size the width of the cell.

Comment: I want the sum of cells' width to be greater than the window width.

Comment: Try to see this Jsfiddle I update it: http://jsfiddle.net/kLetE/4/ is that what you're trying to figure out?

Comment: Yes, I want to same result but with a X-scroll bar on the table if the content of a row exceed the width of the body. (that's why I use 35% for the example)

Comment: Ok, Set a fix width in the table and row then add a overflow:scroll in the css. (width must be px)